# Laravel variable inside html rendered tag

Tags: laravel, email, templates

I want to make a dynamic email template. By "dynamic" I mean the user can change the content: both HTML (static text), and the PHP tag (the name or address).

This is the problem:

- I tried to save the whole template as HTML in my database, and call it using `{!! $data->value !!}`.
- The template worked, and it is rendered as an HTML tag.
- However, the PHP tag is not being rendered. It stays like this: `{{ $demo->demo_one }}` when I send the email.

Does anyone know how to turn the PHP tag into its value? Or maybe there is another way of making a dynamic email template?

Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to recompile your code:

```
{!! Blade::compileString($demo->demo_one) !!}
```

Comment: not the exact answer but help me to find another way, thankyou for helping

Comment: please post your solution

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Ahmed Nour answer, i can found another way

what i did :

copy this function

```
function render($__php, $__data)
{
    $obLevel = ob_get_level();
    ob_start();
    extract($__data, EXTR_SKIP);
    try {
        eval('?' . '>' . $__php);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) ob_end_clean();
        throw $e;
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) ob_end_clean();
        throw new FatalThrowableError($e);
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

then call the function like this

```
foreach ($data as $key) {
        //first i need to get the template from database
        $template = Blade::compileString($key->value);
        $objDemo->template = $this->render($template, ['receiver' => 'Raven', 'demo_one' => 'Demo One Value', 'demo_two' => 'Demo Two Value', 'sender' => 'SenderUserName']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your blade file (consider $email_content as the e-mail content configured by the user):

```
@php
 $email_content = str_replace('{{ $demo->demo_one }}', $demo->demo_one, 
 $email_content);
@endphp
{!! $email_content !!}
```